# circular bit shifting in byte array in java

Tags: java, arrays, bit-shift

How to shift one byte(8 bit shifting) to the left for 16 byte array.?

i.e. Array of 16 bytes: (0x) 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

after shifting 8 bits left:

output should be: (0x) 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 00

How to do this in java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one (not very elegant) way:

```
byte[] bytes = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0xa, 0xb, 0xc, 0xd, 0xe};

// now shift left
byte b0 = bytes[0];
System.arraycopy(bytes, 1, bytes, 0, bytes.length -1);
bytes[bytes.length - 1] = b0;
```

Comment: @laune - done, although OP did specifically ask about a 16-byte array.

Comment: Hello, Answer is very useful, but as you mentioned "Not very elegant" way, should I accept the answer or possibility of any other better optimized way?

Comment: This calls a "native" method, so it'll very likely use s.th. like memmove. Maybe you'd be faster using 16+1 explicit assignment statements, but I doubt very much that it's worth doing that.

Comment: @MihirShah - The "not very elegant" part is that it is not very general, not that its performance could be improved. It only shifts by one and only to the left. If I were writing the code for myself, I'd be strongly tempted to generalize (shift left or right; shift by more than one byte) and also to package it in a method--unless the requirement was iron-clad guaranteed never to change. (Hah!) As laune points out, loop unrolling is likely to be the only way to make this faster, and the performance gain will likely be minimal.

Comment: @Ted Hopp - Thanks a lot sir. I am using this as requirement will not be changed.